# Preferred method to mass update in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have `10,000` `Person` `Objects` in my Realm database, all I have are the IDs of each person. I've been profiling the different solutions I have come up with to update all the names on each Person object.

In my test application I retrieve all the IDs using the following.

**The code below is only run to fetch IDs for the tests, in the real application I would already have the IDs**

```
var ids = [String]()
for person in realm.objects(Person) {
    ids.append(person.id)
}
```

**First approach to update all names for 10,000 Person objects**

```
realm.write {
    let people = realm.objects(Person).filter("id IN %@", ids)
    for person in people {
        person.name = "lionpants"
    }
}
```

**Second approach to update all names for 10,000 Person objects**

```
realm.write {
    for id in ids {
        let person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Person.self, key: id)
        person?.name = "lionpants"
    }
}
```

Surprisingly both approaches averaged about `1200ms` runtime (including fetching the IDs) using the Xcode Time Profiler (I thought the first approach with the predicate would be faster).

Personally, I prefer the second approach due to the lack of predicates. But, is there a preferred/different approach when mass updating with Realm? Maybe I'm missing some built in functions?

Answer (score 7):

```
realm.write {
    let people = realm.objects(Person).filter("id IN %@", ids)
    people.setValue("lionpants", forKey: "name")
}
```

Should be slight faster, and in general using KVC on results like that will be more performant, as Realm can take some shortcuts under the hood.

Comment: Applying this solution in my test project results in about a 600ms runtime, definitely faster. I think I'll stick with the "Second approach" for now though due to compiler safeness, etc. Not a fan of magic strings. Your solution is definitely handy if the performance is needed though, thanks!

Comment: is it possible to share anyone it for objective-C?